# Do all OrientDB master nodes have the same data?

Tags: cluster-computing, orientdb, database-replication, consistency, multi-master-replication

Do all master nodes update their states when we dynamically add them into an OrientDB cluster? I mean if we already have a running master node with some data, can we be sure this data will be replicated to a new master node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends by the configuration. By default you have a full replica, so as soon as a new node joins, the entire database is deployed on the new node (`autoDeploy:true`).